# List Rake Tasks WIthout Namespace

Tags: ruby, rake

My Rakefile contains a few tasks without a namespace. When I run `rake -T`, those tasks are not listed. How do I include them? I tried writing my own task to list them all and it kind of works, but it only lists the names and not the descriptions.

```
task :list do
  Rake.application.tasks.each do |task|
    print task.name() + ' ' + task.comment.to_s() + "\n"
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you can provide your Rakefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tasks have preceding `desc`s, the *are to be listed* in `rake -T`:

```
desc "Lists all the tasks"
task :list do
  Rake.application.tasks.each do |task|
    puts "#{task.name} \# #{task.comment}"
  end
end
```

Tasks w/o preceding `desc` are omitted in `rake -T` output by design. If you still want to use your `:list` task, simply add

```
Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true
```

to the very top of your main `Rakefile`.

Comment: I was putting the `desc`s inside the task, not before it. Thanks for clearing that up.